# encode and decode bytes in xml strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, byte

I'm looking for a way to write and read byte data in xml files. I'd like the xml files to be human readable, so I'd like to avoid base64 encoding or anything similar. I figured I could do something like this. If I have a string `b'abc < ABC\x04&'` that needs to go into a tag `<node>`, then I'd write that as

```
<node>abc &lt; ABC&#x04;&amp;</node>
```

Is there a way to make this kind of encoding work with any xml library in python3? I'd prefer `lxml`, but that's not a requirement.

**Clarification**: When I write an xml file, the strings are initially of type `bytes`, e.g. `b'abc < ABC\x04&'`. In a lot of cases they only contain alphanumeric ascii characters, which I want written to xml as such. Other bytes I want to encode as hex values, so they can still be easily understood. And I'd like to encode characters like `>` and `&` as `&gt;` and `&amp;` (or else also as hex values) to avoid using `<![CDATA[<]]>`. When I read the strings, I'd like them to be converted back to `b'...'`, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure there is no builtins that accomplish **exactly** what you ask

I think the best you could do is just iterate over the characters and "fix" each one (see example that i think is complete)

```
try: # python2
  from htmlentitydefs import codepoint2name
except: # python3
  from html.entities import codepoint2name

def encode_xml(c):
  # return the character or its &#XX; or &entity; representation
  ascii_val = ord(c)
  known_entity =  codepoint2name.get(ascii_val,None)
  if known_entity: # this is a named codepoint
    return "&%s;"%(known_entity,)  
  # printable characters are ascii values [32..127] inclusive
  is_normal_character =  32 <= ascii_val <= 127
  if is_normal_character:
      return c
  return hex(ascii_val).replace("0x","&#")+";"


def make_xml_entity_string(s):
  return "".join(encode_xml(c) for c in s)

print("R:", make_xml_entity_string( 'abc < ABC\x14\xF2&'))
```

you could then go the otherway ... in roughly the same manner (taking advantage of regex this time though)

```
try: # python2  
  from htmlentitydefs import name2codepoint
except: # python3
  from html.entities import name2codepoint
import re

def decode_xml_replacer(match):
  name=match.group(1);
  if(name.startswith("#")):
    return chr(int(name[1:],16))
  return chr(name2codepoint.get(name,'?'))

def decode_xml_string(s):
  return re.sub("&(.*?);",decode_xml_replacer,s)
```

... note that this wont work for codepoints > 255 i think

Comment: That's a pity that libraries don't seem to implement this as an option. Encoding is not the biggest problem here, because it can be done before calls to an xml library. The real problem is decoding, because a library will try to do it itself, and at least `lxml` appears to choke on bytes < 32. For example, `etree.fromstring('<x>a&gt;bc&#x80;</x>').text` gives `'a>bc\x80'`, but `etree.fromstring('<x>a&gt;bc&#x14;</x>').text` chokes claiming `invalid xmlChar value 20`.

Comment: I guess I could keep the `\x14` sort of encoding and parse that myself, and only substitute characters bad for xml, e.g. `<`.